# How to modify '{}' argument passed to -exec by the find command?

Tags: bash, find

I have find command like this:

`find <some criteria> -exec echo "{}" \;`

But I would like to modify "{}" argument before echo is called.
For example deprive it of the first path segment (${*variable*#*/}) and leave the rest.

I know that I can call another script after -exec but I prefer to have everything in one script.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not pipe find to sed?

Comment: Right! I should have thought of this before. Shame.

Comment: I'll write it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pipe it to `sed` like this:

```
find <some criteria> | sed "s,.#*/,,"
```

Comment: thanks, `find <some criteria> | sed "s,.#*/,," | xargs -0 echo` works

Answer (score 3):

you can use an inline sh-script:

```
find tmp -exec sh -c 'basename "{}" | wc' \;
```

Comment: With `-exec sh -c 'basename "$1" | wc' _ {} \;` you could avoid code injection

Comment: `basename` does not do the same thing as `${path#*/}` if the path has more than two components. @thatotherguy's method allows the use of parameter expansion forms: `find -exec sh -c 'echo "${1#*/}"' _ {} \;`. Although in this particular case, it's possible that the solution is the `%P` format directive to `exec`'s `-printf` action. (Assuming Gnu find).